# Johnson graphs in Mathematica

Tags: math, matrix, wolfram-mathematica, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have a question about defining Johnson graph in Mathematica software. I find this in Stackoverflow and It works:

```
johnsonmatrix[n_, k_] := 
 Module[{s = Select[Subsets[Range[n]], Length[#] == k &]}, {s, 
    MatrixForm[
    Table[If[Length[Intersection[s[[i]], s[[j]]]] == k - 1, 1, 0], {i,
       Length[s]}, {j, Length[s]}]]}]
```

But I can't use its matrix. How can I only have the adjacency matrix of this roll? In fact, I want to define Johnson graph in Mathematica software and then find some properties of this graph like its spectrum. I appreciate if anybody can help me.

Comment: You should be aware there is a [site here just for Mathematica users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you know enough to understand the implications, most of the time using any of the *Form functions, like `MatrixForm` and `DisplayForm` and etc, etc, etc, are only to transform something that can be used for calculations into something pretty to look at, but which cannot be used for any further calculations.

Try getting rid of the `MatrixForm` and see if this will give you some ideas where to go with this.

```
johnsonmatrix[n_,k_]:=Module[{s=Select[Subsets[Range[n]],Length[#]==k&]},
 {s,
  matrix=Table[If[Length[Intersection[s[[i]],s[[j]]]]==k-1,1,0],{i,Length[s]},{j,Length[s]}],
  adjacencygraph=AdjacencyGraph[matrix],
  adjacencymatrix=AdjacencyMatrix[adjacencygraph];Normal[adjacencymatrix],
  eigenvalues=Eigenvalues[adjacencymatrix],
  spectrum=Max@@Abs[eigenvalues]
}]
johnsonmatrix[5,3]
```

Please check every detail of this very carefully to try to make certain that I have made no mistakes.

Comment: Hi, thank you, It was very helpful to me. I'm a new trainer of mathematica software. I appreciate if you help me again. I want to define a graph which it has the k and n-k subsets of the set {1,2,...,n} as its vertices and two vertices are adjacent if and only if one of them is the subsets of the other how can I do it ? Thank you so much for your time and aid

Comment: Study this `n=5;k=3;vertices=Join[Subsets[Range[n],{k}],Subsets[Range[n],{n-k}]]; edges=Flatten[Outer[If[SubsetQ[#1,#2]||SubsetQ[#2,#1],#1<->#2,Nothing]&,vertices, vertices,1],1];Graph[edges,VertexLabels->"Name"]` Look up every one of those functions in the help system and try to figure out exactly what is being done. There is a lot going on in that. Make absolutely certain that this is exactly correct before you trust it.

Comment: A VERY important part of this is learning how to figure out these things for yourself instead of learning how to ask the internet for the answers. Don't underestimate how important that is. It is too easy to think you understand it after someone has shown you the answer and more difficult to develop the skill of learning how to solve problems on your own. That skill is what you will need in the future.

Comment: yes, you are completely right but in my country you don't have much sources or people you may learn from it. I would like to write program in Mathematica and I very like to learn it but i don't know anything about it I just can work with prepared function I can't write what is in my mind. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Wolfram offers free classes and free introduction to their language over the internet. There are lots of pdf versions of older books available free on the internet, but I would be very careful to avoid viruses and malware. From what you say I think finding a pdf book like "Mathematica Navigator" or other old Mathematica book and reading the entire book more than one time would be the way for you to make the most progress. After that you can read the Mathematica documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/  and look at the examples and begin to understand why they work and modify them